# Passing data to service in oncreate()

Tags: android

I am passing the data from main activity to service.

I am getting these errors in Myservice.java
 1. In override oncreate method - method does not override from superclass
 2. The displayingText in run - cannot resolve symbol.

Mainactivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//load the layout file


}
String displayingText = "ABC";
public void StartService(View v) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(mIntent);//(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services
    mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

MyService.java

```
 public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if service is  already existed
    if(mTimer!=null)//if mTimer is activated
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);// schedule task

}

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Please share your project with me?

Comment: ankit, what do you mean? 
Do you mean to upload the whole file to you? or share with you the concept?
--i am new here, so i actually not figured out where to upload the file, haha

Comment: Ya I mean can you share with me on Google drive?

Comment: May I know what is it for?
Maybe should i just paste the service file and mainactivity code here?

Comment: But I have to compile here  my making proper files and all. If you don&#39;t want to send then it&#39;s ok. Thanks

Comment: what is your email?

Comment: ankitpatidar030@gmail.com

Comment: @Anthony you want your activity data in Service Right ??

Comment: @Subhash Yes, any suggestion?

Comment: @Anthony you can get your passed data in on startCommandMethod in service :)

Comment: @Anthony Please check my answer if its worked then vote thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problem in your code .

**1.change the order of the code**

```
public void StartService(View v) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    // edited here
    mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
    startService(mIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My code

```
String displayingText = "abc";

public void StartService(View v) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(mIntent);//(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services
    mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**2.register in your manifest for your service**

```
<service android:name=".your_package.MyService"/>
```

Registered as

```
<service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

But the value return nothing.

Comment: yup check is ur service registered

Comment: Yes, no 1 and 2 done. as per my answer to wai yan. But the value is nil in the service

Comment: Could you show more code about this ?  XML code@Anthony

Comment: <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" />

Comment: have to use intent putextra first then start service., Thanks a lot

Comment: Good luck to you.@Anthony

Answer (score 0):

for StartService(View v)....
you still haven't implemented any action or event in onCreate method.

if you still have can't resove problem, use "Mainactivity.this" in place of this in StartService method.

Comment: `public void StartService(View v) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(mIntent);//(new Intent(this, MyService.class));//use to start the services
        mIntent.putExtra("PassToService",displayingText);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`
I had edited them, but still the outcome for the value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to service like below :-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , GPSTracker.class);
    intent.putExtra(YOURKEY , VALUE);
    startService(intent);
```

and you can get your data on `onStartCommand()` method :-

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null){
            intent.getStringExtra(YOURKEY)
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

I had done as below. But the toast message return no character(no value)

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
    Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: That's working I check in my code would you please share your code so I will check Nd get back to you soon :)

Comment: Thanks Subhash.
have to use intent putextra first then start service. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sry, since KeliuYue had given the answer first. 
Thanks for you help. Appreciate them.

Comment: you still vote my answer if you like otherwise alwz wlcm bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onStartCommand to get the data/values from the activity to service.,

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         return START_STICKY;    
}
```

after this you can override the oncreate method and display the stuffs.

But you need to remember that **ALWAYS ONCREATE METHOD WILL BE EXECUTED WHEN WE USE startservice method in our activity**

In Your Activity, just use the below code:

```
private void initializeService(String Index) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Detail_Test_run.this, Servicelay.class);
        intent.putExtra("Index",Index);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Then in your service use:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        index= intent.getStringExtra("Index");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        addView(index);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
```

For me it worked well, where I started calling all my functionalities from onStartCommand() instead of onCreate()

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use sharedpreferances as data wont be available for service in background.
So in your startService() method:

```
   public void StartService(View v) {
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(mIntent);
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("data",displayingText).commit();
                            editor.apply();}
```

And in your service class's onStartCommand() add these lines

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String string = prefs.getString("data","");
```

Hope this helps :)